# Cartão de Cidadão em Node

Tags: node.js

Boas pessoal
Alguém já tentou ou conseguiu correr o cartão de cidadão com o node?
Não consegui pô-lo a trabalhar mesmo depois de ter instalado o middleware...

https://svn.gov.pt/projects/ccidadao/browser/middleware-offline/trunk/_src/eidmw/eidlibNodeJS_Wrapper

Estou a utilizar o exemplo fornecido, mas parece-me que está demasiado desactualizado...

Comment: Boas conseguiste alguma coisa com o eidlibNodeJS_Wrapper?